# Can we clean up/delete the tag 'object'?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

The tag [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) seems to be used for an interesting variety of questions - not at all related to each other. The tag on its own does not add any information - a classic meta tag. The generic excerpt doesn't help either,

> An object is **any entity that can be manipulated by commands in a programming language**. An object can be a value, a variable, a function, or a complex data-structure. In object-oriented programming, an object refers to an instance of a class.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

Tag stats,

- 19250 questions in total,
- 7% are closed,
- 55% have a score of <0.

Thoughts? Can we deallocate the memory used by this tag (or at least tidy it up)?

Comment: Here is query that shows which tags go together: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=object   that might help to decide which combinations are OK-ish and which can be removed instantly

Comment: Funny to see Javascript in second place, just before Java... New users understand it is useless to put the tag `object` with a full Object Programming language ? :D

Comment: Not worth the time.

Comment: I haven't used the object tag. It just too abstract for a clean instance of a question. With no research, I am willing to speculate that its abuse is through new-ish contributors to SO.

Comment: I've seen a few people use it semi-legitimately for questions about new-style vs. classic classes in Python. (Before Python 3.0, you have to inherit from `object` explicitly, or another new-style class, if you don't want to get the broken old behavior.) Some people don't know what to call a new-style class, but they know `object` is relevant.

Comment: (PS, the reason I say "semi-legitimately" is that there's really no need for a tag to distinguish new-style and classic classes in Python; there's only a handful of good questions that could usefully be asked under such a tag.)

Comment: @MaximeLorant  In JavaScript  `object`   does narrow things down quite significantly from just  `JavaScript`

Comment: @MikeBrockington That's what `javascript-objects` is for

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Does _that_ tag ever get used - not one I've ever seen in the wild.